# How to unmark 'allow executing file as program' for all files with the same extension

Tags: 15.10, nemo

Nemo asks me if I want to execute .txt or .r files when I click to open it, I would have to unmark manually all .txt or .r files to be able to open them directly with `gedit` or `rstudio`.

So my question is:

How to unmark  'allow executing file as program' for all files with the same extension?

I am using Nemo on Lubuntu.

Thanks.

Comment: Under preferences > default applications for LXSession, what do you have listed for text editing?

Comment: Hello, it is `gedit`.

Answer (score 1):

The solution is the following for .txt files, the extension can be changed; also 664 permission can be changed to 660 to forbid file access to others:

```
find . -name  \*.txt -exec chmod 664 '{}' \;
```